# Wordpress not going to custom post type page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a custom Wordpress theme.  I added some custom post types to `/wp-content/themes/my-theme/wp-includes/post.php` like so

```
// 1. when registering a custom post type set show_in_menu to false,
function register_project_custom_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Projects', 'post type general name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Project', 'post type singular name', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Projects', 'admin menu', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Project', 'add new on admin bar', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Project', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Projects', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Projects', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Projects:', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No projects found.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No projects found in Trash.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true, 
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'project' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-nametag',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'project', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_project_custom_type' );
```

When I go to the url `http://localhost/my-project/project/uma-thurman/` for one of these it is falling back to my index.php and not my single.php.  I have tried `single.php`, `archive.php` and `single-project.php`.  Nothing seems to work.

I updated my permalinks and I thought based on the hierarchy that Wordpress was supposed to handle things like this automatically.

Comment: You're missing a fair number of details that would help troubleshoot this more.  For example, what URL are you visiting that is "falling back" to your index.php template?  Second - have you gone in the dashboard to the permalinks section and saved? (This is required after adding new post types).  Where is the code you've posted above? (In what file - a plugin? Your theme? If your theme, where?)  Are you confident the above code is running? How?

Comment: Ah.  It's been a few years since I've worked with Wordpress and the second you mentioned saving the permalinks I thought it must have been that.  Alas, it still isn't working.  I changed the permalink back to default ```http://localhost/my-project/?project=uma-thurman``` and it still isn't working.

Comment: The code is definitely running.  It shows up on my admin panel, I was able to add custom fields to it and fill them out.  It's in ```wp-includes/post.php```

Comment: You modified `wp-includes/post.php`?  If so, that's a core WP file, and you _never, ever, ever_ should modify core WP files.  The next time WP updates, those changes will be lost

Comment: No. I put it in the folder of my theme as one should. I did not edit the wp-includes file outside of my theme.

Comment: BTW, going to the index page actually means it's a 404 - it would be useful for you to _confirm_ that is the case...

Comment: My guess at this point is that you may have a permalink collision. Change the slug to something else that's DEFINITELY unique, save your permalinks, and let us know if that changes anything.

Comment: Would turning debug mode on tell me that it was indeed a 404 error or should I look in the network tab?

Comment: So change ```project``` to something else is what you're saying?  Thanks for your help btw.

Comment: Yes, change the slug to something like `project-xyzpdq` or something so you can be 100% confident there's no slug collision.

Comment: I updated to a custom slug and it is still falling back to the ```index.php```  -____-

Comment: So, please forget about the templates for the moment.  I mentioned above it was likely falling back to index because it was actually a 404 error.  Please determine if that is the issue.  If it IS the issue, then a Google search for "Wordpress custom post type 404" will almost certainly turn up many existing resources / answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else falling into this issue I had to switch to a different theme and then switch back.  For some reason the custom post type wasn't completely recognized until doing this.